# Selenium keeps printing data:, to window name

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Selenium, just started looking at it a few days ago.
Here's my program.
It just basically opens a website, nothing too much.
But it does not loads the window, just prints `data:,` to the window header, and a white background color pops up.

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/home/MyName/_DEV_/Selenium/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('google.com')
#driver.close()
```

What can be the problem? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: try `https://www.google.com`

Comment: @venky__ same... :/

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: Here's the link for the picture:
https://ibb.co/ZctbyqQ

Comment: Try: `driver.get('https://google.com')`. That is, specify a valid URL. Also, do `driver.quit()` rather than `driver.close()`.

Comment: @Booboo Same. Did not helped. :(

Comment: Update your question with your updated source and include any output (error messages, stack traces, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
First made `sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver`, than

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(https://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand being new. I have provided you a little "template" on what I use as a basis to help you get started. 
( Note: I use this in my own custom classes; but, for demonstration purposes, I put it all into one file for you ).

**MAIN PROGRAM - For Reference**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as ChromeDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as DriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as DriverConditions


def get_chrome_driver():
    """This sets up our Chrome Driver and returns it as an object"""
    path_to_chrome = "F:\Selenium_Drivers\Windows_Chrome85_Driver\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    
    # Browser is displayed in a custom window size
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1500,1000")
    
    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chrome,
                            options = chrome_options)

    
def is_displayed(driver : ChromeDriver, xpath : str, timeout = 5):
    """Checks if our element displays on our page. If it does, return True. Otherwise, return False."""
    try:
        webElement = DriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            DriverConditions.presence_of_element_located(locator = (By.XPATH, xpath))
            )
            
        return True if webElement != None else False
    except:
        return False


# Gets our chrome driver and opens our site
chrome_driver = get_chrome_driver()
chrome_driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
result = is_displayed(chrome_driver, "//input[@title='Search']")
print(f'Does Search Textbox Display: {result}')
chrome_driver.quit()
chrome_driver.service.stop()
```